# How to translate the site ID in the generated audit log report to site URL so that it can be easily readable?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have generated the audit log report into an excel file but I cannot understand the site ID. Any idea on how I can translate the site ID into the site URL?

Answer (score 0):

It's by design and there is no way to change the audit log column.

At the top of the report, there is a column referencing the Site URL:

[image]

Comment: How about retrieving the site URL using the site ID?

Comment: Please check the latest reply.

Comment: Yup, I noticed the site URL is at the top. But using only the site ID will I be able to map the site ID to the site URL using PowerShell or CSOM?

Comment: $site = Get-SPSite 'Site Id'

Get-spsite $site | select Url